# Can i safely change my BIOS to UEFI only?

Tags: bios, windows-11, uefi

I have windows 11, and decided that i want to turn on secure boot. Problem is, my BIOS is UEFI with CSM, and not UEFI only, so i'd like to change that. As far as i know my drivers are GPT, but i'm still not too sure about changing the BIOS. Will my drives get formatted or maybe my pc won't boot anymore? I just want to make sure i won't mess something up.

Comment: Please read my comment under the answer before you do something you will regret later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CSM enabled then your boot disk can **not** be GPT, as Windows will not boot from a GPT disk under BIOS emulation, therefore you will need to convert it.

Intel have a guide at [How to Convert the System from Legacy BIOS mode to UEFI mode after Installing Windows](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000024558/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)

There are a lot of words on that page that go into checking that your system actually has an MBR disk and that ***you should always make sure you have a good backup before proceeding*** but the general process is only 4 steps.

> 1. Open Command Prompt with administrator privileges.
> 2. Run the following command: `mbr2gpt.exe /convert /allowfullOS`
> 3. Restart the system and boot into the system BIOS.
> 4. Change the settings from Legacy BIOS mode to UEFI mode.

I have personally done this on a system many years in the past and it did actually work. It really can be that simple.

But, this needs to be said, some things **can** go wrong. It being simple is no excuse for not having a good backup.

Comment: CSM enabled doesn't preclude a (correct, proper) installation in UEFI mode. Many firmwares still to this day have the CSM/Legacy option with typically 3 "switches": UEFI only, UEFI + Legacy and Legacy only. The latter is the only one that forces a Legacy installation. The mode is determined by how we boot the installer and, of course, with Windows it strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode and MBR to Legacy/CSM. In conclusion, it's perfectly possible for the OP to have CSM enabled and at the same time Windows correctly installed (UEFI, GPT). (...)

Comment: (...) Disabling CSM won't have any effect other than precluding boot with Legacy-only installers. Fortunately for everybody the advent of Windows 11 that removed support for Legacy mode, the hardware/firmware will soon have UEFI only options accordingly and not a second too late.